# gradle unable to resolve " compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'" dependency

Tags: java, android, material-design

## my gradle.build dependencies portion

```
  depenencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
     }
```

Comment: there is 3 gradle files. In wich one did you add these dependencies ??

Comment: i have same problems in studio so i used eclipse

Comment: build.gradle(module: app)

Comment: Try this: `implementation 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.5.0@aar'`